# Yesod devel cpu overhead

Tags: haskell, yesod

Yesod development server "yesod devel" on my system(arch linux) uses more then 30%-50% cpu when idle (watching for changed files). I'm guessing it is polling info about changed files from disk? I read a post a year ago about adding [hinotify](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hinotify) (yesod 1.0.1 was forked with this change [yesod fork](https://github.com/trilogysci/yesod)) and I see that newer yesod version (1.1.9.3) has [fsnotify](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fsnotify-0.0.3) added (which is the same thing, but cross platform). I read somewhere that it works with the fallback described above (reading changes from disk) so does anyone know if this could be the case?

First I thought it was garbage collector running, but I run yesod devel with GC off but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is file watching, which may have issues and fallback to polling depending on your setup. You can use the -t option to specify a polling interval instead